# Image Class Function not working correctly due to path

Tags: php, unix, nginx, centos, wamp

I'm using the below function:

```
  class Image {

    static function url($id, $type = 'maps') {
        $path = UPLOAD_DIRECTORY . '/' . $type . '/';
        $files = glob($path . $id . '.*');
        if (count($files)) {
            $ext = substr($files[0], strpos($files[0], '.') - strlen($files[5]));
            return SERVER_URL . 'img/' . $type . '/' . $id . $ext;
        } else {
            return '';
        }
    }

}
```

It works fine when hosted on WAMP but when using on Unix running on nginx it doesn't display the image correctly because of the file path. It seems to add the physical path of the files in the URL so it thinks the patch of the file is http://localhost/demo/img/maps/20/public_html/demo/img/maps/20.png

On WAMP it displays correctly ie the URL is http://localhost/demo/img/maps/20.png

These are the defined variables:

```
define('SERVER_URL', 'http://localhost/demo/');
define('UPLOAD_DIRECTORY', dirname(__FILE__) . '/img');
```

id=20;

Physical location of the images are in /public_html/demo/img/maps/

How can I fix this on a unix OS.

Comment: can you edit the subject, to make it meaningful? to add `PHP` as tag to your list of tags. And to organize the contents of your question, as it's not clear what you trying to ask.

Comment: thanks for the feedback.

Answer (score 0):

Managed to work out a solution (btw I'm not a programmer).

Basically on the UNIX server the directory where the images were located had a dot in the path whereas on wamp it didn't.

So what I had to do is use the strrpost instead of strpost - this finds the position of the last occurrence of a substring in a string instead of the first occurance.